# String interpolation in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a String like this

```
str = "My Name is {0} and My age is greater than {1} years."
```

I want to format this into

```
My Name is XYZ and My age is greater than 17 years.
```

I have tried using `def f = sprintf( str , name, age)` but it's not working. Is there any way to work upon this?

Comment: Hello, could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095769/string-interpolation-in-groovy#) your question to format code properly? That way would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Groovy String interpolation. Just define `name` and `age` variables you can interpolate in a `GString`:

```groovy
def name = "XYZ"
def age = 17

def str = "My Name is $name and My age is greater than $age years."

println str // prints: My Name is XYZ and My age is greater than 17 years.
```

If you want to use `sprintf`, you need to use `%s` to format string variables correctly.

```groovy
def name = "XYZ"
def age = 17

def str = sprintf("My Name is %s and My age is greater than %s years.", name, age)

println str // prints: My Name is XYZ and My age is greater than 17 years.
```

Check the official documentation page for more information about string interpolation in Groovy - https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation